# Why can't write the id=show attribution with the show function?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
 

function show(){
    table_show = '<table id="show">';
    table_show += "<tr>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "id" + "</td>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "date" + "</td>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "type" + "</td>";
    table_show += "</tr>";
    table_show += "</table>";
    var parent = document.body;
    var tmp = document.createElement("table");
    tmp.innerHTML = table_show;
    parent.appendChild(tmp);
}

ob = document.getElementById("bShow");
ob.addEventListener("click",show);
```

```html
 
<input id="bShow" type="button" value="show_table">
```

I want to  add a new table with `show` function,when you click the button to invoke the show function via addEventListener, the new table created ,but without the `id="show"` attribution in it ,why?
The first line in show function is :

```
table_show = '<table id="show">';
```

Why no `id="show"` in the new table created?

[image]

Comment: Because you did `document.createElement("table");`. Either append the tag's `outerHTML` like with `<table id="show">`, or use `document.createElement('table')`, but not both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute *id* must be unique in a document, use class instead. You also do not need to use `createElement()` to create the table again as it is already in the *htmlString*.

You can use `parent.innerHTML += table_show` to update the HTML in the container.
You can also use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to insert the *htmlString* into the DOM.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("container");
function show(){
  table_show = '<table class="show">';
  table_show += "<tr>";
  table_show += "<td>" + "id" + "</td>";
  table_show += "<td>" + "date" + "</td>";
  table_show += "<td>" + "type" + "</td>";
  table_show += "</tr>";
  table_show += "</table>";
  parent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', table_show);
}

ob = document.getElementById("bShow");
ob.addEventListener("click",show);
```

```html
<input id="bShow" type="button" value="show_table">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [CertainPerformace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9515207/certainperformance)'s comment, the issue is related to creating a `table` then appending another `table` to it. As this is not valid HTML, one is removed by the browser (or any number of things that the browser decides to do).

The following will work and create valid HTML.

```js
function show(){
    table_show = "<tr>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "id" + "</td>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "date" + "</td>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "type" + "</td>";
    table_show += "</tr>";
    var parent = document.body;
    var tmp = document.createElement("table");
    tmp.setAttribute("id","show");
    tmp.innerHTML = table_show;
    parent.appendChild(tmp);
}

ob = document.getElementById("bShow");
ob.addEventListener("click",show);
```

```html
<input id="bShow" type="button" value="show_table">
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `var tmp = document.createElement("table");` removing your `id` attribute. Because `document.createElement` always return a virgin DOM element. Slightly update your show `function()` like following snippet:

```js
function show(){
    table_show = '';
    table_show += "<tr>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "id" + "</td>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "date" + "</td>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "type" + "</td>";
    table_show += "</tr>";
    var parent = document.body;
    var tmp = document.createElement("table");
 tmp.id = 'show';
    tmp.innerHTML = table_show;
    parent.appendChild(tmp);
}

ob = document.getElementById("bShow");
ob.addEventListener("click",show);
```

```html
<input id="bShow" type="button" value="show_table">
```

Answer (score 0):

You created 2 table tag,

```
table_show = '<table id="show">';
```

and

```
var tmp = document.createElement("table");
```

use just 1 tag, if you want go with javascript, use [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method for add attribute 'id' to your element 'table'.

Answer (score 0):

Another way also pointed by `CertainPerformance`,solve it with `outerHTML`.

```js
 

function show(){
    table_show = '<table id="show">';
    table_show += "<tr>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "id" + "</td>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "date" + "</td>";
    table_show += "<td>" + "type" + "</td>";
    table_show += "</tr>";
    table_show += "</table>";
    var parent = document.body;
    var tmp = document.createElement("table");
    parent.appendChild(tmp);
    tmp.outerHTML = table_show;
}

ob = document.getElementById("bShow");
ob.addEventListener("click",show);
```

```html
 
<input id="bShow" type="button" value="show_table">
```